# Create a struct pointing to another

Tags: rust

How can I create the `Item` instance pointing to the database received as parameter?

```
struct Something {}

struct Database<'a> {
    something: &'a Something,
}

struct Item<'a> {
    database: &'a mut Database<'a>,
}

impl<'a> Item<'a> {
    fn new(database: &'a mut Database) -> Self {
        let mut obj = Self { database };

        obj
    }
}
```

This produces the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:13
   |
16 |             database
   |             ^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected type `&'a mut Database<'a>`
              found type `&'a mut Database<'_>`
note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 13:1...
  --> src/main.rs:13:1
   |
13 | / impl<'a> Item<'a> {
14 | |     fn new(database: &'a mut Database) -> Self {
15 | |         let mut obj = Self {
16 | |             database
...  |
20 | |     }
21 | | }
   | |_^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 14:5
  --> src/main.rs:14:5
   |
14 | /     fn new(database: &'a mut Database) -> Self {
15 | |         let mut obj = Self {
16 | |             database
17 | |         };
18 | |
19 | |         obj
20 | |     }
   | |_____^
```

I do not understand if the error is in the return type (Self) or another thing.

Comment: `fn new(database: &'a mut Database<'a>)` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6730b7904bbaa119765d6ae1f8c01422&version=stable))

Comment: Consider updating your rustc version: Stable and nightly both report "explicit lifetime required in the type of `database`" and even suggest adding the `'a` lifetime. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9eea1f8ee97a74d42f03a5542f089d1e&version=stable))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined `Database` to require a lifetime parameter.  That means you also have to give it one.  The error message is really helpful here and your problem is fixed by simply doing what it says:

```
expected type `&'a mut Database<'a>`
   found type `&'a mut Database<'_>`
```

It suffices to simply add `<'a>` to `Database` in the signature of `new`.

N.B.: Always read error messages from top to bottom.  Usually by resolving the first error all the successive ones disappear.

```
struct Something {}

struct Database<'a> {
    something: &'a Something
}


struct Item<'a> {
    database: &'a mut Database<'a>
}

impl<'a> Item<'a> {
    fn new(database: &'a mut Database<'a>) -> Self {
        let mut obj = Self {
            database
        };

        obj
    }
}

fn main() {
    let something = &Something {};
    let mut database = Database { something };
    let item = Item::new(&mut database);
}
```

<kbd>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6730b7904bbaa119765d6ae1f8c01422&version=stable)</kbd>

Comment: It is perhaps helpful to think of the difference between the lifetime of the reference and the lifetime of the object. In this context it seems they are the same and the compiler should be able to figure that out, but as I understand it, lifetimes are more an annotation the compiler proves are true rather than a thing the compiler "figures out." There are inference rules for providing default lifetimes, but they are fairly simple and designed to be always safe.